# How to minimise the UINavigation bar like the Safari?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Here is the UINavigation bar in the Safari...
[image]
How to make the navigation bar minimise like this? Thanks.

Comment: may try hiding navigation bar when user starts scrolling and use the table section/custom view to change the ui similar to safari..

Comment: It may not be a real navigation bar, but a view that mimics one. If you really want something offer a 100 pt bounty for code that does as mobile a safari does and you will surely get some response.